# How to batch insert data into two tables with a 1:n relationship using?

Tags: java, postgresql, groovy, one-to-many

I want to insert data in two tables with a 1:n relationship. The amount of data is quite huge so I want to use a batch statement to insert into my tables. Problem is, when I do that with my "parent" table, I'm unable to assign the data in my "child" table to the corresponding parent entry.

I have three tables, let's say the first is called Data, the second is Employee and the third is EmployeeData. In the table Data is some huge amount of data I'm gonna process in my application. Now after I processed the data I have a dataset for several employees. First I want to create a entry for every employee in my dataset in the table Employee and then create entries for the corresponing data of that employee in my EmployeeData table.

```
Sql sql = new Sql(conn)

employees.each {
    def employeeId = sql.firstRow("select coalesce(max(id), 1) from employee")

    sql.executeUpdate("""
        insert into employee (id, firstname, lastname)
        values (:id, :firstname, :lastname)
    """, [id: employeeId, fistname: it.firstname, lastname: it.lastname])

    sql.withBatch("""
        insert into employee_data (id, working_hours)
        values (nextval('employee_data_id_seq'), :hours)
    """) { stmt ->
        employees.data.each {
            stmt.addBatch([
                    hours: it.hours
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using groovy sql for the interaction with the database. Sadly I also can't use auto increment in my database for some reasons, so I wrote my own sequence to generate my ids for the insert. This is a simplyfied version of my actual stuff, in the real application my tables have a lot more columns. There are about 300.000 datasets to insert into EmployeeData.
This works but it takes quite some time to insert all the data. Is there a better way to tackle this task?

Comment: could you insert all the data into 3 tables with 3 batches and without using `each`? this would be more efficient...

Comment: also withTransaction increases the speed of insertion. for example `sql.withTransaction{ sql.withBatch{...} }` works faster. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch(int,groovy.lang.Closure)